# Items in the set $A = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{N}_0 \times \mathbb{N}_0 \times \mathbb{N}_0 \mid x + y + z \in \{ {9, 10}\}\}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

We define set $A$ as follows:

$$A = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{N}_0 \times \mathbb{N}_0 \times \mathbb{N}_0 \mid x + y + z \in \{ {9, 10}\}\}$$

My understanding is that this gives all the possible ordered triplets for which we will get the sum of $9$, then separately the same for the sum of $10$.

**Is this the right interpretation?**

and if so, what is |A|?

This is my process, please correct me if I'm wrong:

this needs to happen twice because we can have the sum be either 9 or 10, then we can just add the two results together
n = 9, k = 3

We then get $\binom{9+3-1}{3-1}$ = $\binom{11}{2}$ = 55

And for the 2nd part, let n = 10 and we get $\binom{10+3-1}{3-1}$ = $\binom{12}{2}$ = 66

so |A| = 121

Comment: Thank you for fixing the latex, i tried to get it sorted but must have missed a parenthesis

Comment: Yes, $A$ is the set of ordered triples of nonnegative integers with sum $9$ or sum $10$.

Comment: You don't need the brackets round the whole thing.

Comment: Do you need to find all those triplets, or just find the _number_ of those triplets? For the latter, use [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: @StinkingBishop they did ask for the cardinality of the set, i was just going to ask how to find that... But obviously i needed to ensure i understood the notation and what they were asking for. thank you!

Comment: @StinkingBishop is |A| = 121

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Interpretation is Correct.

It will give Set $A=\{(1,1,7),(1,1,8),(1,2,6),(1,2,7),(2,3,4),(2,3,5),....\}$ , huge set with dozens of triplet elements.

**It may aid to know a little more , hence I am Posting this Answer.**

(1) $\mathbb{N}_0 \times \mathbb{N}_0 \times \mathbb{N}_0$ will generate all ordered triplets.

Then the given Criteria will filter-out all elements which add up to some other total , & that will filter-in those elements which add up to $9$ or $10$.

(2) When you have that Definition , you might utilize it , like this Example :

$[ (x,y,z) \in A ] \iff [ (x+y+z = 9) \lor (x+y+z = 10) ]$
(this is almost some new alternate Definition of the Same Set)

You might even utilize it like this :

If $x+y+z=9$ then $(x,y,z+1) \in A$ & $(x,y+1,z) \in A$ & $(x+1,y,z) \in A$

These are just additional things , Your Interpretation is Correct.

**ADDENDUM:**

OP has included a new query on $|A|$.
When checking with sum of $9$ , we get $55$ triplets.
When checking with sum of $10$ , we get $66$ triplets.
Hence $|A|=55+66=121$.
OP already knows the calculations , hence I am not elaborating it more.

When we take Positive $x,y,z$ (non-Zero) , the counts are $28$ & $36$ , giving total $64$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Appreciate the edit